# Proj/PyProj Convert between ocentric and ographic latitudes

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

I am trying to use Pyproj to perform the conversion between ocentric and ographic latitudes. I can do this using the `cct` command line tool:

```
echo 0 45 | cct -z0 +proj=geoc +a=3396190 +b=3376200
  0.0000000000   44.6617680466        0.0000           inf
```

based on the docs [here](https://proj.org/operations/conversions/geoc.html).

When attempting to do this with Pyproj, I would expect to be able to define the projects and then apply the transformation. Something akin to:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
ocentric = Proj(proj='geoc', a=3396190, b=3376200)
ographic = Proj(proj='latlon', a=3396190, b=3376200)

ographic(0,45)
```

I can get the ographic projection to instantiate without an issue, but the ocentric projection fails with an invalid CRS error: `CRSError: Input is not a CRS: +proj=geoc +a=3396190 +b=3376200  +type=crs`

Has anyone been able to define a geocentric projection on a custom ellipsoid? If so, how?

Note: I also tried:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
ocentric = Proj(proj='latlon', geoc=1, a=3396190, b=3376200)
ographic = Proj(proj='latlon', a=3396190, b=3376200)

transform(ocentric, ographic, 0, 45)
```

and I get an error that the input is not a transformation. I believe that `geoc` is being silently ignored in this example.

## Update

I was able to define a pipeline to make the conversion work as follows. Thanks @snowman2.

```
trans = pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline('+proj=pipeline +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +step +proj=geoc')
lon, lat = trans.transform(0, np.radians(45), errcheck=True)
np.degrees(lat) = #44.6617680466192
```

Note the weird np.radians call. When I run this transformation using 45 (as in degrees, which should be the default because radians=False is the transform default) I see: `ProjError: transform error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits`.

Comment: Did you try `Transformer.from_pipeline`?

Comment: @snowman2 Updated the post. The pipeline works, but the arguments are not making sense when compared to the doc string. Specifically, the `yy` arg should default to degrees, but it appears to be in radians. Setting `radians=False` does not appear to have any effect.

Comment: No unit conversions happen when using the pipeline in the current version. When version 3 comes out, the unit conversions will happen automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the input from @snowman2 I was able to find a solution:

```
trans = pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline('+proj=pipeline +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +step +proj=geoc')
lon, lat = trans.transform(0, np.radians(45), errcheck=True)
np.degrees(lat) = #44.6617680466192
```

The inverse is then:

```
itrans = pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline('+proj=pipeline +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +step +proj=geoc +inv')
nlon, nlat = itrans.transform(lon, lat, errcheck=True, radians=True)
print(nlon, np.degrees(nlat))
```

The unit conversion is expected because of how the pipeline works. The [proj pipeline documenation](https://proj.org/operations/pipeline.html) was really good for helping with the syntax of the Proj string.